# How to verify if a string is an alphanumeric combination (contains both letters and digits) #linux #Bash

Tags: linux

## Bash

I have tried this:

```
a="abc123"
if ! [[ $a =~ [^a-zA-Z0-9] ]]; then
    echo " a is alphanumeric"
else 
    echo " a is not alphanumeric"
```

But this function verifies if the string has only letters or only digits, not both and i don't know how to make it work. I check on google but found nothig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
a="abc123"
if ([[ $a =~ [a-zA-Z] ]] && [[ $a =~ [0-9] ]]); then
    echo " a is alphanumeric"
else 
    echo " a is not alphanumeric"
fi
```